# Replacing text with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to replace a pattern in my json file with Ruby. Input file has:

```
p={'x': 1534804991, 'y': 0.1}
```

I want the output:

```
p={:x=>1534804991, :y=>0.1}
```

I tried using `gsub`

```
p.gsub(''x'',':x=>')
p.gsub("'x'",":x=>")
p.sub!(\w/x\w/, ":x=>")
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Is your `p` variable a Hash object?

Comment: `{'x': 1534804991, 'y': 0.1}` isn't JSON, JSON would use double quotes on the keys. Do you have JSON or a JavaScript object literal that may or may not be valid JSON?

Comment: This looks like an XY-problem.

Comment: How does your JSON file look like, exactly? And why do you want to change it? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the point on what you want is transforming - or getting a new representation of your hash - with its keys as symbols rather than as String as you currently show in your input example.

For doing that transform_keys would work:

```
hash = {'x': 1534804991, 'y': 0.1}
p hash.transform_keys(&:to_sym) # {:x=>1534804991, :y=>0.1}
```

If your Ruby version doesn't support transform_keys, you can use each_with_object, or any of the "old" ways:

```
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v }
```

In order to change to value of a key in a hash, you must access its elements (key, value), and over there, do the manipulation or the assignation (to a new object).

Comment: the transformation is unnecessary `:'x' == :x #=> true` so `{'x': 1534804991, 'y': 0.1} == {x: 1534804991, y: 0.1}` is also `true`. Now if the original `Hash` was `{'x' => 1534804991, 'y' => 0.1}` then the transformation would be required

Answer (score 0):

I guest what you meant is:

```
p = File.read('xxx.json')
# => "{'x': 1534804991, 'y': 0.1}" 

puts p
# => {'x': 1534804991, 'y': 0.1}
```

If so, using `gsub` like the following would work.

```
puts p.gsub(/'(\w+)': /, ':\1=>')
# => {:x=>1534804991, :y=>0.1}
```